# Sorting list of lists with depth more than 2

Tags: python, sorting

I have the list a list of the following type:

```
x = [ [[5,"j"],[1,3,4]] , [[5,"a"],[2,0,8]] , [[5,"d"],[3,0,2]] , [[5,"c"],[8,7,6]] ]
```

I want to sort this list based on the element `x[i][0][1]` ( `i` being any integer within the length of the list). I have been trying to use `itemgetter()` and `x.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])`. I tried different variations using these two ways but am not getting the expected output and would need some guidance on the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your explanation, to do that, you can use `sorted` with `key` argument like below:

```
x = [ [[5,"j"], [1,3,4]] , [[5,"a"], [2,0,8]] , [[5,"d"], [3,0,2]] , [[5,"c"], [8,7,6]] ]

sorted_list = sorted(x, key=lambda item: item[0][1])
```